# Re-using result of an EF JOIN query (lambda) to build another query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, join

I was wondering if it is possible to use the result from an `Entity Framework` join query.

Please ignore whether the join query makes sense or not. I'm just trying to explain my issue rather than having a correct query. I simplified it quite a bit for clarity sake:

```
var firstJoinQuery = (from company in this.TimesheetsContext.companies
                      join country in this.TimesheetsContext.Countries
                      on company.CountryId equals country.Id
                      where (country == 'USA')
                      select new { CountryId = country.Id }).Distinct();

var secondJoinQuery = (from country in this.TimesheetsContext.Countries
                      join firstJoinQuery
                      on country.CountryId equals firstJoinQuery.CountryId
                      select new { Country = country }).Distinct();
```

I'd swear I've done it before but I just can't get the result of one join to be used in the second or the third.

The reason I want to do this is to keep things easier to read as it's not always obvious while using EF and complex queries.

My current work-around veer towards an actual stored procedure as it will definitely be easier to read but if possible, I'd like to give it a shot in EF first.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine two query with [Union](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.union?view=netframework-4.8).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it, but you need use `.ToList()` on your queries, cuz `Distinct()` execution like deferred. Here you try join query like query string, not result query.

```
var firstJoinQuery = (from company in this.TimesheetsContext.companies
                      join country in this.TimesheetsContext.Countries
                      on company.CountryId equals country.Id
                      where (country == 'USA')
                      select new { CountryId = country.Id }).Distinct().ToList;

var secondJoinQuery = (from country in this.TimesheetsContext.Countries
                      join firstJoinQuery
                      on country.CountryId equals firstJoinQuery.CountryId
                      select new { Country = country }).Distinct().ToList();
   var thirdJoinQuery .....
```

Answer (score 0):

I eventually figured it out by researching it some more.

I found the following article: [Combining LINQ Queries (or, When to Call ToList)](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/tool-tracker/2015/12/combine-linq-queries.aspx?m=1) which helped.

To resolve my problem I had to return the full object rather than just a property, remove the .Distinct() and the .ToList() so I changed this:

```
var firstJoinQuery = (from company in this.TimesheetsContext.companies
                  join country in this.TimesheetsContext.Countries
                  on company.CountryId equals country.Id
                  where (country == 'USA')
                  select new { CountryId = country.Id }).Distinct().ToList;
```

to

```
var firstJoinQuery = (from company in this.TimesheetsContext.companies
                  join country in this.TimesheetsContext.Countries
                  on company.CountryId equals country.Id
                  where (country == 'USA')
                  select company;
```

I'm not finished playing around with this, nor have I finished my query into a full blown link but if I find anymore, I'll update this answer.

Hope this helps.